# how to decode string in c#

Tags: c#, string

i got the url from user by  encodeURIComponent() in javascript.
the url goes something like

```
"http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com"
```

how i can decode them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HttpUtility.UrlDecode() is the way to go. You find the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx

Comment: +1 for the only suggestion using the actual type name so the OP can find it - the others assuming ASP.NET is fine, but also assuming he the OP must be within the context of a control exposing `Server` is a bit too far.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Server.UrlDecode() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

From the docs:

```
String DecodedString = Server.UrlDecode(EncodedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Server.URLDecode( ). I'm assuming you're talking about ASP.net here - you didn't say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to decode URLs:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net right?

```
string Url = Server.UrlDecode("http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com");
```